# Disable supabase reads but allow real-time updates to anon and authenticated

Tags: vercel, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js, supabase-realtime

I want to use supabase *only* for real-time updates of the PostgreSQL database.

Meaning that I don't want to allow anon/authenticated to read/update/insert/delete, but only want to push live changes using their [Realtime](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/realtime) feature.

Is this possible? (Setting the RLS to be extremely restrictive while still allowing broadcasting of new changes?)

this is perhaps a bit of an XY problem, still it would be nice if this were possible.

I want user requests to go through my server-side code first where I do a number of manipulations before completing their request using api XYZ/Supabase `SERVICE_ROLE`. They should not be able to query any part of the database client-side (even if they were allowed to receive that information realtime), not even for a read, ideally.

---

The reason for this is that I do need a real-time component that cannot be solved by using server-side code (cannot deploy SSE/WS on vercel...)

Right now I use https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/supabase but I've already seen that blocking anon/authenticated from reading rows also (obviously) blocks him from receiving realtime updates.

---

Ideally I want something unidirectional and that can be restricted to *just* be unidrectional, something like Server-Sent events. Or websockets with no permission to write requests. Is this possible?

Comment: Using soketi/pusher works fine

Comment: Using RLS it's not possible. You would need to setup your own websockets to broadcast only the updates to the users.